# jQuery doesn't return proper body height on document load - Their bug or mine?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

When I use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var bodyHeight = $("body").height();
 console.log(bodyHeight);
});
```

I get a really wack number for body height. I then run

```
$("body").height();
```

in the console and get the right height. Something seems fishy about the $(document).load doing this... Yes my CSS works fine and all, so is this my bug, chromes, or jQuery's?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to look at the `$(window).load()` function rather than `$(document).ready()`.

The `$(document).ready()` event executes when the HTML DOM is loaded and ready, even if all the graphics haven't loaded yet.  The `$(window).load()` event executes later when the complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images.

Here is a great link describing the difference.  http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/

Comment: Thanks! This solved a similar problem that almost drove me crazy!

Comment: Still fires too early, but better than ready... however, setTimeout is still required to get the proper height

Comment: It's likely that your body height is dependent on images in your content. Have a look at imagesLoaded plugin by Desandro.

Comment: I'm with @momo - some of my div tags seem not to be ready in $(window).load()

Answer (score 16):

The `document.ready` event fires after the DOM has loaded but before the page has fully rendered.  If you want to get the correct height, you should try the `window.load` event which fires after all images and objects have been loaded and the page has been rendered:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var bodyHeight = $("body").height();
});
```

Comment: Cool, Cool. Thanks man. I always had this crazy idea that it would delay my script loading, but that's really no issue with modern browsers!