# How can get the height of a div and set another div to be the same height with JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a bootstrap container with some content center screen. The amount of content in this container may vary. However, I need it to be at least the height of the aside sidebar.

The aside sidebar, with a fixed width, is positioned absolute (Out of the flow of the document) as setting it to position relative caused the container to end up half way down the screen, after the sidebar.

I tried JQuery/Javascript methods to get the height of the aside sidebar onload and set the section tag or container to be of equal height, but this doesn't seem to get the calculation and set the height.

```
    /* CSS */
    section {float: left; border: 1px solid blue;}
    .container {margin: auto; width:60%; background: pink}
    aside {position: absolute; top:0;left:0;}


    <!-- HTML -->
    <section>
        <aside id="aside">
            <ul>
                <li>LINK</li>
                <li>LINK</li>
                <li>LINK</li>
                <li>LINK</li>
                <li>LINK</li>
                <li>LINK</li>
            </ul>
        </aside>
        <div class="container" id="container">
            This container or the wrapping section tag needs to be at least the hight of the aside
        </div>
    </section>

    var left=document.getElementById('aside').style.height;
    var right=document.getElementById('container').style.height;
    if(left>right)
    {
        document.getElementById('container').style.height=left;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('aside').style.height=right;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get full height of element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410765/get-full-height-of-element)

Comment: Use the MatchHeight Plugin. Works really well!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use

```
var clientHeight = document.getElementById('myDiv').clientHeight;
```

or

```
var offsetHeight = document.getElementById('myDiv').offsetHeight;
```

`clientHeight` includes padding.

`offsetHeight` includes padding, scrollBar and borders.

And it returns only number while assigning height again just add `px` with it

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var left=document.getElementById('aside').clientHeight;
var right=document.getElementById('container').clientHeight;
console.log(left);
console.log(right);
if(left>right)
{
    document.getElementById('container').style.height=left+"px";
    
}
else
{
    document.getElementById('aside').style.height=right+"px";
}
});
```

```css
/* CSS */
    section {float: left; border: 1px solid blue;}
    .container {margin: auto; width:60%; background: pink}
    aside {position: absolute; top:0;left:0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- HTML -->
    <section>
        <aside id="aside">
            <ul>
                <li>LINK</li>
                <li>LINK</li>
                <li>LINK</li>
                <li>LINK</li>
                <li>LINK</li>
                <li>LINK</li>
            </ul>
        </aside>
        <div class="container" id="container">
            This container or the wrapping section tag needs to be at least the hight of the aside
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: This works here but not when I copy the code to my example. Im still not getting it to wrap https://screenshots.firefox.com/ceMWwrJjwrvL5wFl/null

Comment: @Al-76 You must be missing something, it should work. If there is no error in console comment a fiddle of your code or update your question with latest code

Comment: No errors at all in the console. I have tried on codepen as well https://codepen.io/Al-76/pen/bYEzYp

Comment: It just worked on Codepen so thank you. But still struggling with it in my project. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158156/discussion-between-sanchit-patiyal-and-al-76).

Comment: Sanchit's code works. However, I have a line of CSS in my bigger project that caused a bug. Now that I have removed it all works ace.

Answer (score 0):

When you got the value of height (left and rigth) you got value with 'px'.
E.g. left = 250px, right = 300px, and that couldn't be used on if statment with > or <.

Solution is that you need first the remove px from value than check which of them is larger, and after that you need  add px on value, i set on container.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery as below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var left=$('#aside').height();
    var right=$('#container').height();
    if(left>right)
    {
        $('#container').height(left);
    }
    else
    {
        $('#aside').height(right);
    }
});
```

```css
section {float: left; border: 1px solid blue;}
    .container {margin: auto; width:60%; background: pink}
    aside {position: absolute; top:0;left:0;}
input[type=text] {
    width: 20em
}

p {
    margin: 1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
        <aside id="aside">
            <ul>
                <li>LINK</li>
                <li>LINK</li>
                <li>LINK</li>
                <li>LINK</li>
                <li>LINK</li>
                <li>LINK</li>
            </ul>
        </aside>
        <div class="container" id="container">
            This container or the wrapping section tag needs to be at least the hight of the aside
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using jQuery.

```js
var left = $('#aside').height();
var right = $('#container').height();
if (left > right) {
  $('.container').height(left);
} else {
  $('.aside').height(right);
}
```

```css
section {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  background: pink
}

aside {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <aside id="aside">
    <ul>
      <li>LINK</li>
      <li>LINK</li>
      <li>LINK</li>
      <li>LINK</li>
      <li>LINK</li>
      <li>LINK</li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
  <div class="container" id="container">
    This container or the wrapping section tag needs to be at least the hight of the aside
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window load instead of ready, because of the reason here:[jQuery doesn't return proper body height on document load - Their bug or mine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853839/jquery-doesnt-return-proper-body-height-on-document-load-their-bug-or-mine)

```
$(window).load(function() {
     var left=$('#aside').height();
        var right=$('#container').height();
        if(left>right)
        {
            $('#container').height(left);
        }
        else
        {
            $('#aside').height(right);
        }
    })
```

Useful links:

http://api.jquery.com/height/

[Get height of div with no height set in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592575/get-height-of-div-with-no-height-set-in-css)

You tagged as JQuery, so rather tackle this using JQuery than native JS.
Try to use JQuery when you can if you have it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in vanilla javascript.

```js
var left = document.getElementById('aside')
var leftHeight = left.clientHeight;
var right = document.getElementById('container');
var rightHeight = right.clientHeight;

console.log(leftHeight, rightHeight)
// Do the style manipulation after the DOM is loaded
window.onload = () => {
  if (leftHeight > rightHeight) {
    right.style.height = leftHeight + "px";
  } else {
    left.style.height = rightHeight + "px";
  }
}
```

```css
/* CSS */

section {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  background: pink
}

aside {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<section>
  <aside id="aside">
    <ul>
      <li>LINK</li>
      <li>LINK</li>
      <li>LINK</li>
      <li>LINK</li>
      <li>LINK</li>
      <li>LINK</li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
  <div class="container" id="container">
    This container or the wrapping section tag needs to be at least the hight of the aside
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You should see other answers before posting yours and check it it is same or not

Comment: There were no answers when i opened the question and when i submitted there were 7 answers. People are too fast here. :)

Comment: True, but hey! we are here to help :) We find a lots of perfect answers in this site, from the simplest to the most mind boggling problems.. Who knows someone might be facing the exact same problem.

Comment: Spent 2 hours trying to sort it with various JQuery solutions, CSS, Javascript research still nothing that I can get working. We're not all experts!

Comment: Did any of the solution work? using .clientHeight and concatenating "px" to height in plain javascript should make it work.